# Is it possible to receive data on the same IP and port simultaneously

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, python-multithreading

I am trying to make it so that, during any point in my client-server program, if the client wishes to exit the program, it sends data which the server will be able to receive no matter what the timing is.

To do this I have tried to use threading to run a thread in the background that listens for data "quit" in the background
Whilst in the non threaded part of my code, it simply takes data as normal

Here is my attempt which (of course) did not work

Client:

```
import socket

host = str(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))  # Gets local IP so I don't have to keep changing
# host = "192.168.0.17"
port = 1000
ID = "__UserLogin123__"
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))
while True:
    x = input("Send QUIT? -> ").upper()
    if x == "Y":
        s.send(str.encode("QUIT"))
    else:
        s.send(str.encode("foo"))
```

Server:

```
import socket
import queue
from threading import Thread

def foo(conn):
    while True:
        x = conn.recv(2048).decode()
        if x == "QUIT":
            return True
        if x == "foo":
            print("hollo")


result = False
port = 1000
host = str(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
que = queue.Queue()
connThread = Thread(target=lambda q, arg1: q.put(foo(arg1)), args=(que,conn))
connThread.start()

while not result:
    print("Waiting")
    test = conn.recv(2048).decode()
    if test == "foo":
        print("hi")
    result = que.get()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not usually solved by multiple threads but rather by more layers. You simply create an additional layer, which will check only for quit word. If the processing word is not quit, then pass the word to the upper layers (your application logic). If yes, then don't pass anything up and simply quit the program.

Comment: The only problem is that my actual program receives data at multiple points (A function or method which is called by another function or method) and the proper response to quitting is found there. Do you suggest I completely restructure my code or?

Comment: @JamesGreen I think this is the best solution. The receiving logic should be encapsulated at one place, at least for propper OOP architecture. This will be in fact another layer, the lowest one.